# Dependency injection hell, what is expected?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angularjs-service

I'm trying to separate components into several files for a simple application but angular's dependency injector is giving me headaches and I don't really know what is expected.

```
Unknown provider: servicesProvider <- services <- maincontroller
```

Is the error I'm getting.

app.js

```
//Application definition with injected dependencies
var app = angular.module('leadcapacity', ['services', 'utils', 'customfilters', 'controllers']);
```

services.js

```
var services = angular.module('services', []);

services.service('xrmservice',
[
    '$http', function($http) {

        var oDataUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + '/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/';
        var service = {};

        service.query = function(entitySet, query) {
            return $http.get(oDataUrl + entitySet + '?' + query);
        };

        return service;
    }
]);
```

controllers.js

```
var ctrls = angular.module('controllers', ['utils', 'services']);

ctrls.controller('maincontroller',
    function ($scope, services, utils) {



    };
});
```

And the include order in `index.html`

```
<script src="service.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Looks fine to me. I know this is perhaps not the best way to organize things, but getting a "Hello world" first would be nice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error message appearing in console clearly says that, `services`
>   dependency isn't exists in the module.

You have injected incorrect service name in `maincontroller` controller factory function, basically you were trying to to inject `services`(module name) instead of `xrmservice`(service name)

```
function ($scope, services, utils) {
```

should be

```
function ($scope, xrmservice, utils) {
```

---

**Additional**

Do follow Inline Array annotation of DI, as you were already used the same in your `xrmservice` service JS file, so that in future you don't need to go back and change that when you face javascript minification related issues.

**Controller**

```
ctrls.controller('maincontroller', [ '$scope', 'xrmservice', 'utils',
    function ($scope, xrmservice, utils) {

         //code goes here
         //....
    };
}]);
```

Comment: OK this is weird. I thought I would have access to `services.xrmservice` in the controller. Thanks.

Comment: np. Glad to know that it helped, Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Although you have injected them into the module, you need to give them to the function so you can use the injected modules

```
ctrls.controller('maincontroller',
    ['$scope', 'services', 'utils', function ($scope, services, utils) {


    };
}]);
```